# Different section headers in UITableView of a nested NSArray

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to learn how to code a UITableView and is having some problems with the programming of the section.

I have declared 3 arrays with strings and 1 array with the 3 arrays.

```
firstSection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Blue", nil];
secondSection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Orange", @"Green", @"Purple", nil];
thirdSection = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Yellow"];

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstSection, secondSection, thirdSection, nil];
```

To shows the headers

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

NSString * title;
title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , [array objectAtIndex:section]];

return title;
}
```

which shows the array itself as the headers

[image]

therefore is it possible to actually show the name of the sections using the names of the arrays such as firstSection and secondSection?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want here - the name of the array, eg "firstSection" ? Or an item from inside the array, eg, "Red" ?

Comment: Yes I want to show the names of the arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, it's better to store your arrays in an `NSDictionary`. For example, if you declare and synthesize an `NSDictionary` variable called `tableContents` and an `NSArray`  called `titleOfSections`, you can do something like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //These will automatically be released. You won't be needing them anymore (You'll be accessing your data through the NSDictionary variable)
    NSArray *firstSection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Blue", nil];
    NSArray *secondSection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Orange", @"Green", @"Purple", nil];
    NSArray *thirdSection = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Yellow"];

    //These are the names that will appear in the section header
    self.titleOfSections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name of your first section",@"Name of your second section",@"Name of your third section", nil];

    NSDictionary *temporaryDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:firstSection,@"0",secondSection,@"1",thirdSection,@"2",nil];
    self.tableContents = temporaryDictionary;
    [temporaryDictionary release];
}
```

Then in the table view controller methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [self.titleOfSections count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.tableContents objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",section]] count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Setting the name of your section
    return [self.titleOfSections objectAtIndex:section]; 
}
```

Then to access the contents of each array in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    NSArray *arrayForCurrentSection = [self.tableContents objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayForCurrentSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that you have created a third array called titleOfSections and put the names in it. Is it possible to show the names of the array itself without doing so?

Comment: Well I guess thats the only way. Thanks

Comment: I am complete noob and I don't know if there is a better way to do it. But this worked really well for me. Thanks @sooper

Answer (score 0):

can u do like this

```
  NSArray   *SectionArray = [[NSArray alloc]initwithArray:[array objectAtIndex:section]];

  NSString * title;

  title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , [SectionArray objectAtIndex:section]];

   return title;
```

Comment: That won't work as thirdSection has only 1 item, so in the case of section = 2, index would be out of range. I'm not sure wakaka has really made clear what he wants...