# UITableview sections (Xcode 4.5 and iOS6)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITableview with 2 sections. The first section should contain only one row and the second section should contain 6 rows. How do I define the number of sections? From the storyboard I could define that my table view style is grouped.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Marcos

Comment: You should read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView) of `UITableView` before asking. Your answer is there and you will definitely understand better how it works going through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supply all of that information at runtime, generally from the view controller. You need to set your view controller as the table view's 'data source', then implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol which is documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

The specific method that will determine how many sections are presented is this one:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the sections were defined from the interface builder and not at runtime.

Comment: I've just realized that if my table view is a static table view, it’s possible to define the number of sections in the storyboard (no code needed).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocols to populate a table with sections and rows. See the Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Check the solution I submitted for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156094/1064869); it should point you in the right direction.